# Css3 Animation looping in webkit-animation

Tags: html, css, animation, webkit

I have a problem with css3 animation effect.I want to know how to continue looping without go to start place.
As a example. when clouds are moving, the webkit-animation time over, it come to first step and start animate again.So it not nice  because cloud go to back and again start moving (watch 7 seconds), i want to continue animation without cloud goes to start.

[DEMO Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lo7csjnu/1/)

CSS3

```
.sky {
        height:638px;
        background:#007fd5;
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
        -webkit-animation:sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
        -moz-animation:sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
        -o-animation:sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)
    }


    .moon {
        background:url("http://montanaflynn.me/lab/css-clouds/images/moon.png");
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        height:85%;
        width:300%;
        -webkit-animation:moon 50s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation:moon 50s linear infinite;
        -o-animation:moon 50s linear infinite;
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)
    }


    .clouds_one {
          margin-top: -55px;
        background:url("http://montanaflynn.me/lab/css-clouds/images/cloud_one.png");
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        height:80%;
        width:400%;
        -webkit-animation:cloud_one 5s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation:cloud_one 5s linear infinite;
        -o-animation:cloud_one 5s linear infinite;
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)
    }

    .clouds_two {
        background:url("http://montanaflynn.me/lab/css-clouds/images/cloud_two.png");
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        height:80%;
        width:400%;
        -webkit-animation:cloud_two 7s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation:cloud_two 7s linear infinite;
        -o-animation:cloud_two 7s linear infinite;
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)
    }

    .clouds_three {

        background:url("http://montanaflynn.me/lab/css-clouds/images/cloud_three.png");
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        height:75%;
        width:400%;
        -webkit-animation:cloud_three 10s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation:cloud_three 10s linear infinite;
        -o-animation:cloud_three 10s linear infinite;
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        -o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes sky_background {
        0% {
            background:#007fd5;
            color:#007fd5
        }

        50% {
            background:#007fd5;
            color:#007fd5
        }

        100% {
            background:#007fd5;
            color:#007fd5
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes moon {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            left:-200%
            -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
        }

        50% {
            opacity: 1;
            -moz-transform: scale(1);
            left:0%
            bottom:250px;
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        }

        100% {
            opacity: 0;
            bottom:500px;
            -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes cloud_one {
        0% {
            left:0
        }

        100% {
            left:-200%
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes cloud_two {
        0% {
            left:0
        }

        100% {
            left:-200%
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes cloud_three {
        0% {
            left:0
        }

        100% {
            left:-200%
        }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes sky_background {
        0% {
            background:#007fd5;
            color:#007fd5
        }

        50% {
            background:#000;
            color:#a3d9ff
        }

        100% {
            background:#007fd5;
            color:#007fd5
        }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes moon {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            left:-200%
            -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
        }

        50% {
            opacity: 1;
            -moz-transform: scale(1);
            left:0%
            bottom:250px;
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        }

        100% {
            opacity: 0;
            bottom:500px;
            -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
        }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes cloud_one {
        0% {
            left:0
        }

        100% {
            left:-200%
        }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes cloud_two {
        0% {
            left:0
        }

        100% {
            left:-200%
        }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes cloud_three {
        0% {
            left:0
        }

        100% {
            left:-200%
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="sky">
  <div class="clouds_one"></div>
  <div class="clouds_two"></div>
  <div class="clouds_three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you looking for effect where clouds go trough whole screen and only to one direction?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. May be setting a fiddle with only one cloud  would help.